# xml schema verifying single and multiple tags

Tags: xml, xsd

How can I build a schema to validate xml that can contain both single and multiple instances of a tag within a group?

The tags within CO and AS may appear in any order (removing sequence as an option). CUST.NAME, FED.ID and CUST.ADDRESS1 can appear only once in CO. AS is unbounded (removing all as an option).
Ex.

```
<FormData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Stack.xsd">
  <CO>
    <CUST.NAME>mlb2</CUST.NAME>
    <FED.ID></FED.ID>
    <CUST.ADDRESS1>abc st</CUST.ADDRESS1>
    <AS>
      <EQUIP.COST>1.00</EQUIP.COST>
      <EQUIP.DESC>asDesc</EQUIP.DESC>
      <MODEL>UpdFromUDAction</MODEL>
    </AS>
    <AS>
      <EQUIP.COST>1.00</EQUIP.COST>
      <EQUIP.DESC>asDesc</EQUIP.DESC>
      <MODEL>UpdFromUDAction</MODEL>
    </AS>
  </CO>
</FormData>
```

This is the schema I have so far but it does not fail if duplicate CUST.NAME, FED.ID or CUST.ADDRESS1 tags exist.
Using

```
<xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

within COType as there are several other tags that may exist (ex. CUST.ZIP).
Schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsd:simpleType name="CO.FED.IDType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:maxLength value="20" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:simpleType name="CO.CUST.NAMEType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:maxLength value="150" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:simpleType name="CO.CUST.ADDRESS1Type">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:maxLength value="50" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:simpleType name="AS.EQUIP.COSTType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
      <xsd:totalDigits value="14" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:simpleType name="AS.EQUIP.DESCType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:maxLength value="40" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:simpleType name="AS.MODELType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:maxLength value="20" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:complexType name="COType">
    <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xsd:element name="FED.ID" type="CO.FED.IDType" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xsd:element name="CUST.NAME" type="CO.CUST.NAMEType" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xsd:element name="CUST.ADDRESS1" type="CO.CUST.ADDRESS1Type" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xsd:element name="AS" type="ASType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="ASType">
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element name="MODEL" type="AS.MODELType" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xsd:element name="EQUIP.COST" type="AS.EQUIP.COSTType" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xsd:element name="EQUIP.DESC" type="AS.EQUIP.DESCType" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="FormDataType">
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
      <xsd:element name="CO" type="COType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:element name="FormData" type="FormDataType" />
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: I think this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3526579/626761

I guess it's not going to be pretty. If at all possible, consider introducing constraints on the order of elements.

Comment: Did you have a question?  if so, it would probably be helpful to potential answerers if you asked it instead of leaving it to the reader's imagination.

Comment: @C.M. Updated post to be a question.

Comment: @nodots Thanks for the quick response and link. Attempting to incorporate it into what I need.

Comment: I am still unable get put together what I need after reviewing the link from @nodots. The link provides a good sample but only works with a small set of child nodes (A,B,C). In my scenario there may be hundreds of child nodes of CO that are optional and can occur only once then also hundreds of nodes that are optional and can occur unlimited times.

Comment: Maybe step back and reconsider your context. Do you **have to** create an XSD? Or could you choose an easier method of validation, perhaps programmatically?

Comment: In the application I'm working with (it is an older application and uses delphi as the language and msxml6) xml is the format used to pass, process and store data (client/browser to server to db is all xml). The xml is never de-serialized into objects. The only programmatic method of validation I can think of (without major work) would be to traverse through each node in the data xml to get the value then compare that value against the restrictions of that node. this seems like a performance killer.

Comment: To make matters worse, the schema, or other validation method, needs to be able to be generated dynamically as the customer can add user-defined fields (ex. UD_DATE_EXPIRE) at any of the levels (CO, AS).