# XML Scheme: Complex type using any number of elements any number of times

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, complextype

I am trying to create a schema and have come across this problem, although I have found a solution that should work ([XSD - how to allow elements in any order any number of times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290360/xsd-how-to-allow-elements-in-any-order-any-number-of-times)) in my case it doesn't.

```
<xsd:element name="foo">
<xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:choice>
          <xsd:element ref="p" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> *--element p is complex--*
          <xsd:element ref="f" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> *--element f is complex--*
          <xsd:element ref="summary"/>
    </xsd:choice>
      <xsd:attribute ref="type"/>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

using this to validate the xml below brings back the error 'Unexpected child element':

```
<foo type="###">
    <p type="###">
       <pr date="##/##/##" amount="###"/>
       <pr date="##/##/##" amount="###"/>
    </p>
    <f type="###">
       <fr date="##/##/##" factor="###"/>
       <fr date="##/##/##" factor="###"/>
    </f>
    <p type="###">
       <pr date="##/##/##" amount="###"/>
       <pr date="##/##/##" amount="###"/>
    </p>
    <f type="###">
       <fr date="##/##/##" factor="###"/>
       <fr date="##/##/##" factor="###"/>
    </f>
    <summary>
        <p_summary date="##/##/##" p="####" dis="###" ......./>   
        <p_summary date="##/##/##" p="####" dis="###" ......./>
        <p_summary date="##/##/##" p="####" dis="###" ......./>
    </summary>
</foo>
```

I haven't listed the definitions for p f and summary but they both contain maxOccurs="unbounded" for their respective elements (fr, pr, p_summary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the **<xsd:choice>** that must be **unbounded** here. You correct schema should look like this:

```
<xsd:element name="foo">
<xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element ref="p"/>
        <xsd:element ref="f"/>
        <xsd:element ref="summary"/>
    </xsd:choice>
    <xsd:attribute ref="type"/>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Setting `maxOccurs="unbounded"` by each element (`p`, `f`, `summary`) won't make any difference here. It just allows you to repeat the same element many times, but not mix with others.

Comment: Thanks ColdFusion thats just what I wanted!