# Unique particle error, want to allow multiple child elements in any order

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm trying to validate some existing XML files in my project. An example structure looks like:

```
<resources>
    <file name="one" path="C:\test\one.txt" />
    <cache path="C:\test\cache\" />
    <file name="two" path="C:\test\two.txt" />
    <bundle name="myFolder">
        <file name="three" path="C:\test\three.txt" />
        <file name="four" path="C:\test\four.txt" />
    </bundle>
    <file name="one" path="C:\test\one.txt" />
    <bundle name="myFolder">
        <file name="three" path="C:\test\three.txt" />
        <file name="four" path="C:\test\four.txt" />
    </bundle>
    <file name="one" path="C:\test\one.txt" />
</resources>
```

In words, what I want is a structure with root element `resources`, which has children

- At most one `cache` element, in any order
- Any number of `file` and `bundle` elements, in any order
- `bundle` contains any number of `file` elements

This is my current XSD (drawing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12012599/812786)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:complexType name="cache">
        <xs:attribute name="path" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="file">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="path" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="bundle">
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="file" type="file" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:attribute name="type" />
        <xs:attribute name="name" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:group name="unboundednoncache">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="file" type="file" />
            <xs:element name="bundle" type="bundle" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:group>

    <xs:element name="resources">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <!-- Validates if this next line is removed,
                and the cache element is moved to first -->
                <xs:group ref="unboundednoncache" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element name="cache" type="cache" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                <xs:group ref="unboundednoncache" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This gives me the error:

> Cos-nonambig: File And File (or Elements From Their Substitution Group) Violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During Validation Against This Schema, Ambiguity Would Be Created For Those Two Particles.

I can get the first XSD to validate if I remove the first `<xs:group>` in the XSD and move the `cache` element to be the first child in the XML, but I want the cache element to be valid anywhere.

(Prior to this version I was using:

```
<xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="cache" type="cache" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    <xs:element name="file" type="file" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    <xs:element name="bundle" type="bundle" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
</xs:choice>
```

.. but that allows multiple cache elements, which I don't want either.)

Why does my XSD violate "unique particle attribution", and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your schema document, you have written the content model of `resources` as the equivalent of

```
((file | bundle)*, cache?, (file | bundle)*)
```

This is semantically correct, but an initial `file` element could match either the first of the second occurrence of `file` in the content model.  For reasons best left decently obscure, this is not allowed by XSD.

So you need an equivalent content model which is deterministic.  Not all non-deterministic content models have deterministic equivalents, but yours does:

```
((file | bundle)*, (cache, (file | bundle)*)?)
```

Or, in XSD syntax (reusing your definition of `unboundednoncache`):

```
<xs:group name="cache-plus-noncache">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="cache" type="cache" 
                minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    <xs:group ref="unboundednoncache" 
              minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:element name="resources">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:group ref="unboundednoncache" 
                minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:group ref="cache-plus-noncache" 
                minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

It might be handy to have a tool that read content models, detected violations of the determinism (aka 'unique particle attribution') rule, and either proposed a deterministic equivalent or broke the bad news that the content model has no deterministic equivalent.  The theory has been worked out pretty cleanly by Anne Brüggemann-Klein.  But so far I am not aware of such a tool, and my periodic resolutions to write one have thus far not borne fruit.