# XSD XML all sequence maxOccurs

Tags: xml, xsd, sequence

I trying to create/correct the following XSD to match program logic. Current non-XSD logic allows the following attributes (XML representation below) to be parsed in any ordered.  I am very green with XSD.  This would be a valuable tool for parsing validation. Can XSD be created to allow processing of these attributes in any order to allow maxOccurs for Susp_O_CD?  I know sequence will allow maxOccurs and all doesn't, but Susp_O_CD must be allowed to have up to five values, and any input order for StReas, StReas_N, ListSusp_T, and Susp_O_CD tags are required.

```
<PrimaryReason>
   <StReas>2</StReas>
   <StReas_N>Reason for stop test</StReas_N>
   <ListSusp_T>
       <Susp_T>8</Susp_T>
       <Susp_T>4</Susp_T>
   </ListSusp_T>
   <Susp_O_CD>00100</Susp_O_CD>
   <Susp_O_CD>00200</Susp_O_CD>
   <Susp_O_CD>00101</Susp_O_CD>
   <Susp_O_CD>00201</Susp_O_CD>
</PrimaryReason>
```

XSD:

```
<xs:element name="PrimaryReason" type="Reason_Set"/>

<xs:complexType name="Reason_Set">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="StReas" type="StReas"/>
        <xs:element name="StReas_N" type="StReas_N"/>
        <xs:element name="Tr_ID" type="Tr_ID" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="Tr_O_CD" type="Tr_O_CD" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="EDU_sec_CD" type="EDU_sec_CD" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="EDU_subDiv_CD" type="EDU_subDiv_CD" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="ListSusp_T" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Susp_T" type="Susp_T" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="9"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Susp_O_CD" type="Susp_O_CD"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="5"/>
    </xs:all>   
</xs:complexType>
```

Hopefully this can be done. I did try Group but it doesn't work with all tag. All suggests are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSD 1.0, elements in an `xs:all` particle can only appear zero or one times.

This restriction is lifted in XSD 1.1 to allow any `maxOccurs` value.

So you need to decide whether you can move to XSD 1.1 (which is supported by relatively few schema processors: Xerces, Altova, and Saxon).

Incidentally, it's confusing to refer to your elements as attributes. "Attributes" is a technical term in XML. "name" and "maxOccurs" in your schema document are attributes; "Susp_O_CD" in your instance document is an element.

See also [XSD - how to allow elements in any order any number of times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290360/xsd-how-to-allow-elements-in-any-order-any-number-of-times?rq=1)

Comment: Michael, Thank you for your comments and insights.