# How to have multiple elements in any order?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have this XML

```xml
<contacts> 
        <entry id="10">                                             
            <commonName>Susan Sonntag</commonName>
            <tel>+844332232323</tel> 
            <email>susan23@evermail.com</email> 
            <email>susa112@private.uk</email>
        </entry>
        <entry id="20">
            <commonName>John Balber</commonName>                   
            <email>balber@hatebook.com</email>
            <tel>017297123232</tel>
            <email>home@balber.org</email>
        </entry>
        <entry id="25">
            <commonName>Mary Palmer</commonName>
            <tel>017297123232</tel>
        </entry>
</contacts>
```

I want that `<tel>` and `<email>` occur in any order and also optional (zero or unbounded).
I did it with `xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded"` but I am not sure if it's valid.
It is valid though not sure if this is the correct way.

```xml
 <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">                                   
   <xs:element name="tel" type="telType"/>
   <xs:element name="email" type="emailType"/>
 </xs:choice>
```

AFAIK `xs:choice` means I can use only one of them but `maxOccurs="unbounded` allows me to use all of them in any order.

Is it allowed? If no is there another way?

I am not quite sure what `xs:choice` exactly does. Does it mean the order is irrelevant or I can use an one element?

And what exactly is `xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"`? Does that mean I can use 0 to unlimited elements?

AND how about this?

```
<xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:choice>
    ...
    </xs:choice>
</xs:sequence>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XSD - how to allow elements in any order any number of times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290360/xsd-how-to-allow-elements-in-any-order-any-number-of-times)

Comment: Oh yeah! So, this is a legit way with choice and min/maxOccurs?