# XSD 1.0 unable to make validation of unordered XML

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Suppose I have this validation xsd:

```
<xs:complexType name="MyInfo">
    <xs:???>
        <xs:element name="A" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="B" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:???>
</xs:complexType>
```

And I want it to validate class `MyInfo`, which can have:

1. zero or one element *A*
2. any number of *B*
3. any order of elements

Examples: *ABB, BAB, BBA, BB, A*, etc

In production there will be about 30 of these fields, I just selected *A*,*B* for simplicity. To do this kind of validation I tried using various tags instead of `???` in my schema:

1. `sequence` - enforces order validation, not working
2. `choice maxOccurs="unbound"` - skips `maxOccurs="1"` validation, not working
3. `all` - not allowing `maxOccurs="unbounded"`, not working
4. `any` - allows every woo-doo garbage, not working

Is there a consistent way of completely disable XSD order validation in C#? I rarely ever met a business case where I need to check it. The only solution I have right now is to set it to `choice maxOccurs="unbound"` and validate count of elements after xsd validation, separately.

Comment: I don't believe you can express what you want in XSD. I'm not 100% sure on the reason for the limitation (on `all`) other than I can see that allowing *specific* values of `maxOccurs` (rather than `1` or `unbounded`) would imply having to retain an arbitrary amount of state that may have seemed unpalatable for the streaming use case.

Comment: Well, if you want `xs:all` with `maxOccurs="unbounded"` then use XSD 1.1. You might need third party software not part of the Microsoft .NET (framework) or Core libraries but certainly available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290360/xsd-how-to-allow-elements-in-any-order-any-number-of-times
Please check the answers here

Answer (score 1):

In XSD 1.1 you can do this with `xsd:all`, which removes the restrictions on minOccurs and maxOccurs. It can't be done in XSD 1.0.

In practice with XSD 1.1 I might choose to define the content model as (A|B)* and define the actual constraints in an assertion.

Why didn't XSD 1.0 allow this? I suspect it was a combination of factors. Some people might have considered that your XML isn't a good design, and that XSD was only supposed to be capable of describing well designed XML. Some people might have considered that content models should only be able to describe grammars of a particular class, that can be parsed using a simple finite state machine without counters.